# I didn't think him to be so honest

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, usage

> I didn't think him to be so honest.

How can we change this sentence into comparative degree without changing its meaning or sense?

Comment: Do you mean:  *He was more honest than I thought.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think him so honest.

To be more clear, you can rephrase this sentence as follows, without any difference in meaing.

I thought him not so honest.

To make it a omparative sentence, you can say "He was more honest than I thought", as commented by Jim.

Answer (score 1):

If by your sentence you mean that he is more honest than you expected, you could say:

> - He is more honest than I thought.
> - I thought he was less honest.

Both sentences mean the same, but the emphasis is different. In the first one you're stressing the fact that he is considerably honest, while in the second sentence the emphasis is on the fact that you thought he was not so honest as he is.